# Can you @InjectMock deep stubs without defining a @Mock field?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Can you have `mocks` injected into an `@InjectMock` be deep stubs or do you need to define each mock with deep stubs? It's inconvenient to define an unused field only for the purpose of annotating it with deep stubs.

Example, is there a way to do this without defining injected, since it's never used anywhere?

```
@InjectMocks
private Object testMe;

@Mock (answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
private Object injected;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. You're also stacking up a fun assortment of warning labels:

- From [RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.11/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS):

  > **WARNING:** This feature should rarely be required for regular clean code! Leave it for legacy code. Mocking a mock to return a mock, to return a mock, (...), to return something meaningful hints at violation of Law of Demeter or mocking a value object (a well known anti-pattern).
  >
  > Good quote I've seen one day on the web: **every time a mock returns a mock a fairy dies**.
- From [@InjectMocks](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.11/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html):

  > Mockito will try to inject mocks only either by constructor injection, setter injection, or property injection in order and as described below. If any of the following strategy fail, then Mockito **won't report failure**; i.e. you will have to provide dependencies yourself.
  >
  > **Constructor injection;** the biggest constructor is chosen, then arguments are resolved with mocks declared in the test only. If the object is successfully created with the constructor, then **Mockito won't try the other strategies**. Mockito has decided to no [sic] corrupt an object if it has a parametered constructor.

By allowing InjectMocks with automatic deep stubs, you may find it very hard to reason about which injection style and field population you actually use, and which parts of your test are real versus mocked. This would also prevent you from stubbing or verifying any values other than by getting them directly through your system-under-test, which may incur side effects or otherwise break the boundary between real code and test code.

In short, the answer is "no"; the longer answer is that you should consider refactoring to include proper dependency-injection access and avoid any current [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) violations.